# How to do role base in Java Swing Applications

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8

I am creating a java swing application of a college management system for my university project. I want to give specific access to home page of the application according to the position of the users.
(Eg :- When admin login to the system he can access to all interfaces while a student login to the system he can only access to the some selected interfaces.)

Can I do it using the same home interface and please someone help me how to code it using Netbeans. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a role based swing application you are talking about, retrieve from database type of user logging in (Admin, end-user, etc). Then based on type of role of user further use cardlayout. Your question is then similar to this: [How to create a swing application with multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687427/how-to-create-a-swing-application-with-multiple-pages)